# Websocket allows only 200 connections

Tags: javascript, websocket

I just implemented a simple Websocket system on my server. I am trying to test the maximum number of connections, I made the following code:

**Javascript:**

```
for(var i=0; i<300; i++){
    websocket();
}

function websocket() {
    var wsUri = "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "websocket";
    var ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    ws.onopen = function () { ws.send("User connected"); };
    ws.onmessage = function (e) { writeToPage(e.data); };
    ws.onclose = function () { writeToPage("User disconnected"); };
}
```

Everytime I run it, first 200 users gets connected, after that, all requests have their onclose() called. In web console I get the following errors:

**Mozilla:** *The connection to ws://localhost:8080/MyApp/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading*

**Chrome:** *Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade': upgrade close*

My web application is deployed on `Tomcat 7.0.52`. I read that by default it only allows 200 threads, so I added `maxThreads="1000"` in `conf/server.xml` to both `Connector` and `Executor` but the result is the same.

in **web.xml** I added:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tomcat.websocket.executorMaxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I tried opening 300 websockets with `ws://echo.websocket.org`, and again only 200 worked.

Is this the maximum number of connections my server allows? 
Is this the maximum number of websockets I can create as client? 
Is this a good way of testing heavy load?
How can I increase the number?

Comment: You should also test what happens if you have two machines each create 101 connections. Based on the "`header value is not 'Upgrade'`", I'd *guess* the problem is likely on the server, either due to a configuration-specific limit or a server-resource limit. (I'd guess more likely a configuration limit, since it stops at a nice even 200.) Either way, we need more information about your server.

Comment: I tested it on two client machines as you said and last 2 users from second machine cannot connect. So I guess you are right about the server configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of research I found out that `maxThreads="1000"` actually solved the problem, however Mozilla only allows 200 sockets. So I had to test again from multiple client machines.

> Default maximum number of websocket connections allowed in FireFox is
>   200. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets#Gecko_7.0

Comment: can you please describe in detail where you have configured `maxThreads="1000"` , I also have same problem, at time only 200 connection can open, Its not any client problem, I have tested with different client, So how can i enable my server from more connection to be open

Comment: @U2Answer In file `apache-tomcat/conf/server.xml`, inside tag `<Connector />` and value `maxThread="1000"`

Answer (score 1):

There is default limit in Tomcat 7.
Try to set `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.executorMaxSize` property.
See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html#Tomcat_WebSocket_specific_configuration.

Comment: I tried but the result it the same, or maybe I didn't do it right. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We have get this error between WCF service and Web Socket. It just accept ***200*** connections. Than Our team made adding config file this setting.

```
  <serviceThrottling 
    maxConcurrentCalls="1000" 
    maxConcurrentSessions="1000" 
    maxConcurrentInstances="1000"
  />
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/throttling-in-wcf
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33362/WCF-Throttling